# Flutter with Getx ImagePicker does not work properly

Tags: flutter, null, flutter-getx, imagepicker

**Why does the image update only when I save file?**

image_picker version

```
image_picker: ^0.8.4+3
```

My Code related to ImagePicker

```
// image_picker_controller.dart
// controller
 
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
 
class ImagePickerController extends GetxController {
  File? pickedImageFile;
 
  var seletedImagePath = ''.obs;
 
  void _pickImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    // final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickImage != null) {
      pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    }
 
    update();
  }
 
  void Function() get pickImage => _pickImage;
}
```

view page

```
// user_image_picker.dart
// page screen
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chatting_app/src/controllers/image_picker_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
 
class UserImagePicker extends GetView<ImagePickerController> {
  UserImagePicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CircleAvatar(
          radius: 40,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          backgroundImage: controller.pickedImageFile != null
              ? FileImage(controller.pickedImageFile as File)
              : null,
        ),
        TextButton.icon(
          onPressed: controller.pickImage,
          icon: Icon(Icons.image),
          label: Text('Add Image'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[You can have a look at what happens in this gif link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ebMZ.gif)

When I add image with ImagePicker, DEBUG CONSOLE shows below, and image isn't updated.

```
// DEBUG CONSOLE
D/MediaScannerConnection( 7062): Scanned /data/user/0/com.example.flutter_chatting_app/cache/bc149d80-91bb-487d-b2b7-3597357c4d182105624148556557573.jpg to null
```

but, after I save codes, the image appear. I think the state doens't update, but I have no idea why it happens.

I've googled about this problem, but I couldn't figure it out.

Please, somebody help me.

Comment: Did you call setState() after you have picked the file since Flutter does not know whether to update UI unless you have setState() after you have picked the image

Comment: Thank you, Lakmal Fernando for your comment,
I am trying to use Getx mainly, so I didn't consider using StatefulWidget and setState(). If Getx doesn't work then, I will take your advice. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the default `Stateless` and `GetBuilder` combination and it worked:

```
class ImagePickerController extends GetxController {
  File? pickedImageFile;
  void _pickImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage!.path);
    update();
  }

  void Function() get pickImage => _pickImage;
}
```

and the view:

```
class UserImagePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserImagePicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<ImagePickerController>(builder: (logic) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 40,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            backgroundImage:  logic.pickedImageFile != null
                ? FileImage(logic.pickedImageFile as File)
                : null,
          ),
          TextButton.icon(
            onPressed: logic.pickImage,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
            label: const Text('Add Image'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you P4yam for your answer,
It works, but could you explain why this works and using GetView does not work?

And I also wonder that DEBUG CONSOLE is still showing below,

D/MediaScannerConnection( 7062): Scanned /data/user/0/com.example.flutter_chatting_app/cache/bc149d80-91bb-487d-b2b7-3597357c4d182105624148556557573.jpg to null

Doesn't it matter?

Comment: @김상준  GetView sometimes looks buggy and I remember having this exact same bug befor(I think you can find more about it in getx GitHub repo). And about the log, it is not an error but more of a detailed log fired by a library.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will have a look at getx Github repo :)